# JFrame not reopening. Process finished instead but why?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I created a JFrame which I named JMate. It should contain a button within a SettingsPanel, which when clicked, switches to PlayingPanel.
When you are in the PlayingPanel and try to close the frame by pressing on X button it should bring the SettingsPanel back up.

**Current Behaviour:**
When I launch the application, Frame with SettingsPanel opens.
When I press the button in SettingsPanel, SettingsPanele closes and PlayingPanele opens.
When I close PlayingPanel by Pressing on X, SettingsPanel opens for a few milliseconds and closes again.
The process than remains active but no Frame is visible...

I got it resolved but since I use CardLayout instead of 2 JFrames, the Problem now reoccured.

Why is this happening?

This is how my classes currently look:

```
public class JMate extends JFrame {
    public JPanel activePanel;
    public JPanel container;
    public JPanel settingsPanel;
    public JPanel playingPanel;
    public CardLayout cardLayout;

    public JMate(){
        setTitle("JMate v1.0.0");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

        container = new JPanel();
        settingsPanel = new SettingsPanel(this);
        playingPanel = new PlayingPanel(this);

        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        container.setLayout(cardLayout);

        container.add(settingsPanel, settingsPanel.getClass().getName());
        container.add(playingPanel, playingPanel.getClass().getName());

        cardLayout.show(container, settingsPanel.getClass().getName());
        activePanel = settingsPanel;

        add(container);
        setSize(settingsPanel.getPreferredSize());

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosing(e);
                if(activePanel == settingsPanel){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else{
                    cardLayout.show(container, settingsPanel.getClass().getName());
                    setSize(settingsPanel.getPreferredSize());
                    activePanel = settingsPanel;
                    //TODO: stop engine etc.
                }
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel( new FlatDarkLaf() );
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            System.err.println( "Failed to initialize LaF" );
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(JMate::new);
    }
}

public class SettingsPanel extends JPanel {
        private final JMate jMate;
        private SwitchButton switchButton;
        private EngineSelect engineSelect;
        private VariantSelect variantSelect;
        private JButton startButton;
    
        public SettingsPanel(JMate jMate) {
            this.jMate = jMate;
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
            initComponents();
            setVisible(true);
        }
    
        private void initComponents(){
            switchButton = new SwitchButton();
            engineSelect = new EngineSelect();
            variantSelect = new VariantSelect();
            startButton = new JButton("Start");
    
            engineSelect.setVariantsSelect(variantSelect);
            variantSelect.setEngineSelect(engineSelect);
    
            add(switchButton);
            add(engineSelect);
            add(variantSelect);
            add(startButton);
    
            startButton.addActionListener(e -> {
                jMate.cardLayout.show(jMate.container, jMate.playingPanel.getClass().getName());
                jMate.setSize(jMate.playingPanel.getPreferredSize());
                jMate.activePanel = jMate.playingPanel;
                //TODO: start Engine etc.
            });
        }
    
    }


public class PlayingPanel extends JPanel {

private final JMate jMate;
public PlayingPanel(JMate jMate){
    this.jMate = jMate;
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,600));
    initComponents();
    setVisible(true);
}
private void initComponents() {

}
```

}

Comment: What do you think setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); does?

Comment: I would also suggest using setVisible(false) over dispose in this context - although, I might consider using a CardLayout instead of seperate frames

Comment: Oh of course... I removed exit on close in playingframe and it works again. Thank you. I will take a look into CardLayout

Comment: Seems like this problem has now reoccured after using cardlayout. I updated this post

Comment: Well, you don't need a `WindowListener` with `CardLayout`

Answer (score 1):

> Seems like this problem has now reoccured after using cardlayout. I updated this post

Well, it seems to work okay for, but

- Avoid using `setPreferredSize`.  The size of the component should be calculated via the layout manager.  You can affect the size by using things like `EmptyBorder` (to add additional padding) or via various layout settings (padding/etc)
- Avoid resizing the window programmatically after it's shown, users will not thank you for it.  `CardLayout` will determine the best size for the container from needs of the children.
- Avoid extending from `JFrame` (or other top level containers), you're not adding any new functionality to the class and these classes tend to be complex structures which just add to the issues
- I'd be concerned about the use of `WindowListener` in this case - what does it matter what view the user is on if they want the close the window?

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new JMate());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum View {
        SETTINGS, PLAYING
    }

    public interface Navigator {
        public void show(View view);
    }

    public class JMate extends JPanel implements Navigator {
        public JPanel activePanel;
        public JPanel container;
        public JPanel settingsPanel;
        public JPanel playingPanel;
        public CardLayout cardLayout;

        public JMate() {
            //setResizable(false);

            //container = new JPanel();
            settingsPanel = new SettingsPanel(this);
            playingPanel = new PlayingPanel(this);

            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            setLayout(cardLayout);

            add(settingsPanel, View.SETTINGS);
            add(playingPanel, View.PLAYING);

            show(View.SETTINGS);
        }

        protected void add(JComponent component, View view) {
            add(component, view.name());
        }

        @Override
        public void show(View view) {
            cardLayout.show(this, view.name());
        }
    }

    public class SettingsPanel extends JPanel {
        private final Navigator navigator;
        private JButton switchButton;
        private JButton engineSelect;
        private JButton variantSelect;
        private JButton startButton;

        public SettingsPanel(Navigator navigator) {
            this.navigator = navigator;
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
            initComponents();
            //setVisible(true);
        }

        private void initComponents() {
            switchButton = new JButton("Switch");
            engineSelect = new JButton("Engine");
            variantSelect = new JButton("Variant");
            startButton = new JButton("Start");

            //engineSelect.setVariantsSelect(variantSelect);
            //variantSelect.setEngineSelect(engineSelect);

            add(switchButton);
            add(engineSelect);
            add(variantSelect);
            add(startButton);

            startButton.addActionListener(e -> {
                //jMate.cardLayout.show(jMate.container, jMate.playingPanel.getClass().getName());
                //jMate.setSize(jMate.playingPanel.getPreferredSize());
                //jMate.activePanel = jMate.playingPanel;
                //TODO: start Engine etc.
                navigator.show(View.PLAYING);
            });
        }

    }

    public class PlayingPanel extends JPanel {

        private final Navigator navigator;

        public PlayingPanel(Navigator navigator) {
            this.navigator = navigator;
            //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 600));
            initComponents();
//            setVisible(true);
        }

        private void initComponents() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("MATE!");
            label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 48));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);

            add(label, gbc);

            JButton settings = new JButton("Settings");
            add(settings, gbc);
            settings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    navigator.show(View.SETTINGS);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Using a Navigator and a view enum is so much cleaner. I will use this

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, one way to fix this issue, is to add the following line in JMate Class:
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: The default behaviour is `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` - so maybe not messing with it will solve the immediate issue